# How do I set root for an ASP.NET project B inside project A in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a separate asp.net MVC web project B which has to be placed inside project A (also asp.net mvc). I converted project B to application. I have a domain name for project A. So https://www.A.com points to root of project A. But then in project B, the root still points to https://www.A.com. For example, in project B, `@Url.Action("Validate", "Login")` renders https://www.A.com/Login/Validate. But I actually wanted https://www.A.com/B/Login/Validate. In other words, I would like the root of project B to be https://www.A.com/B, including javascript "/". How do I do that?

This is how the project set up in IIS.

[image: IIS Settings]

I hope I've explained my problem clearly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your application append application name in front of the relative path as long as you host project B as sub-application. It shouldn't make project B misunderstand the root folder.

Did you publish your application correctly?

Architecture:

[image]

Code:

[image]

Rendered html

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't publish, simply copy the whole project into IIS

Comment: Even debug application in IIS, VS don't just copy the whole project into IIS. So please try web deployment tool first.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: So does it mean if I do not use the deploy options in VS, IIS won't be able to determine the root correctly?

Comment: @CodyHung. IIS only need the release version of your application not your whole project. And web deployment also do some settings when you publish to IIS. Simple copy the whole project may corrupt the root.